# Implement In app promotion on subscription with promo code in flutter using in_app_purchases official library

Tags: flutter, in-app-subscription, flutter-plugin, promotion-code, flutter-in-app-purchase

I recently implemented the in-app subscription into my app. Now I am working on adding the promo codes for a subscription. People with promo code can have 15 days trial and after that, they'll be charged.

**https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promo**

Described here we can have promotions on subscriptions by giving the user a free trial period. I have created the promotion in the play console. But when I purchase the subscription there is no way I can add the redeem code or promotion code ( Do my app need to be in production or i can test in alpha track too ).

Please Guide me on this.

Comment: Did you have any solution, or answer?

Comment: found any solutions yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [configure license testers](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777) on the Play Developer Console to test Google Play Billing as mentioned in this [guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test). As for configuring the promo code, it's also done on the same page.

[image: Play Console]

To test the Billing integration on your app, it needs to be published on test track at least. You can visit this [guide](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334) for more details. Once the setup is done, the promotion can be tested. There should be a promo code field on the Purchase Dialog in your app. Here are [other methods](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test#promo) where the promo code can be tested.